# How to get last n tokens from string using "FOR /F" in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('echo 111 222 333 444 555') do (
    echo %%a
)
```

How to get all tokens from 2 to n, if I do not know exact numbers of tokens in the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims= " %%a in ('echo 111 222 333 444 555') do (
    echo %%b
)
```

`tokens=2,*` works quite confusing. It doesn't mean that the tokens from the second to the last are stored in %%a but that %%a is the second and **%%b** is the rest. So if you want to get 222 333 444 555 in one variable you have to use `tokens=1,*`. This will put 111 into %%a and the rest into %%b.